# Infinite stacking of integer quantum Hall systems

Tags: quantum-entanglement, topological-insulators, topological-order, quantum-hall-effect, topological-phase

Let us consider a (3+1)-dimensional system $\mathcal{H}$ constructed by stacking (2+1)-dimensional integer quantum Hall systems $\mathcal{H}_\text{Hall}$, e.g., $E_8$ bosonic systems (or $\sigma_H=1$ electronic systems):
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal{H}\equiv\cdots\text{- }\mathcal{H}_\text{Hall}\text{ - }\mathcal{H}_\text{Hall}\text{ - }\mathcal{H}_\text{Hall}\text{ -}\cdots.
\end{eqnarray}
Whether we should consider this system as a nontrivially topological phase?

If we see its boundary, which is formed by infinitely stacking of chiral edge modes with the same chirality, the boundary theory cannot be trivially gapped. Thus it is reasonable to call the bulk system topologically nontrivial. Also from the bulk viewpoint, its ground state wave function should have long-range entanglement, i.e., we cannot transformed it by local unitary to a product state or atomic state.

However, we also have reason to "define" this system $\mathcal{H}$ to be topologically trivial phase because the above nontriviality can be attributed to the fact that the $\mathcal{H}_\text{Hall}$ is a generator of $\mathbb{Z}$-classification of two-dimensional topological phases. Thus if we still take $\mathcal{H}$ to be nontrivial (3+1)-d topological phase, there seems to be an over-counting.

My question is whether there is a better motivation to let $\mathcal{H}$ be trivial or nontrivial?

(Please note that we do not impose any symmetry although $\mathcal{H}$ accidentally has a translation symmetry along stacking.)

Comment: The idea of treating 2D topological states as a “free resource” when classifying 3D gapped states has been explored in https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.05892 and has led to the notion of foliated fracton phases — equivalence classes under addition of trivial / 2D topological degrees of freedom + local unitary transformations. Is that relevant?

Comment: @NandagopalManoj Yeah, that is related to my question. It seems that we should use the equivalence class you mentioned as a definition of classification of invertible topological phases to avoid such trivial over-counting. That is what I thought more reasonable in the question.

Comment: To add to @NandagopalManoj's comment in https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.03852 they describe explicitly how to stack BF theories (so also CS theories, so QHE systems). The Hilbert space consists of just degenerate ground states, but there are string operators of restricted mobility.

Comment: @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə Thanks for the reference and I will try to understand it.